# RBF network not generalizing well

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm trying RBF for a classification problem. The input matrix is of size 40,000 x 2,500 and output matrix is of size 25 x 2,500. Output matrix consists of 0 and 1 only.

As stated in most examples, RBF can give 100% accuracy in training data, so is happening in my case. However, when I test the network with a new input matrix (of 40,000 x 2,500 dimensions, through **simulate network** in nntool), the accuracy is very poor. I've tried a wide range of SPREAD values, but none of them helped in generalizing the network.

The input dataset values lie between -960.0 to +960.0.

Few SPREAD values that I've tried includes:

```
5e-9, 5e-6, 0.005, 0.01, 0.25, 1.0, 5.0, 100.0, 450.0
```

Some forums have suggested to use unsupervised network for clustering the input data, and use the clustered data as an input to RBF. I've used *k-means clustering with 25 clusters*, but it turned out futile.

Can anyone suggest how testing accuracy of RBF can be improved?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

RBF hidden layer is simpler to be trained in an unsupervised manner, k-means or K-NN can be used to find the **centers** and for **spread** parameter you can calculate the mean of distances between centers of every two closest clusters.
now let N be the number of samples, RBF network needs at least N/2 centers(hidden nodes) in theory. your input size is 40,000 and you only had 25 centers for k-means, do it again with 20000 clusters and see if it works. your hidden layer size is too small. weights of output layer should be calculated in a supervised manner, with gradient descent as far as I know.